# How to populate datalist on new page in View Scope?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dashboard with number of items on it. One of them is "Teachers". I am using `<h:link>` to go to `show-teachers.xhtml` which has a search box on it initially. Scope of this bean is view scope and it has two methods:

1. `getAllTeachers` - This method is void as it is called when user clicks on the search button and results are populated on the page using datalist and rendered is set to true to display the datalist. **This work fine.**
2. `getAllStudentsByTeacher` - Once I have the list of teachers from above method the next step is to fetch the list of students under a specific teacher and list them using datalist on a new page(`show-students.xhtml`).

Above method fetches the list of students from the database and return string `show-students` which is another XHTML page on which I want to show the list of matching students using datalist.

But I always get result `No records found` on `show-students` page.

When I change the scope of this bean to session, it works fine. But I would like to use either request or view scope.

Please suggest me If I am missing anything as I am learning JSF/Primefaces :)

Thanks
Rahul Saraswat

Comment: How do you access the student list in the target bean that matches the outcome `show-students`? You could directly inject the (student) list using `@ManagedProperty`, if the target bean (`Student`) is a **request scoped JSF managed bean**. If it is however, not an alternative then, pass a teacher id from the `Teacher` bean (the names `Teacher` and `Student` are taken arbitrarily) to the `Student` bean as a query string parameter from the action(Listener) method. To be continued.

Comment: (to do so, take `teacherId` as  a field with a getter in the `Teacher` bean, initialize it to a value and bind it to an `<f:viewParam name="teacherId" value="#{teacher.teacherId}"/>` and the parameter will then be added automatically). Get/obtain this parameter in the target `Student` bean and fetch a list of students associated with that `teacherId` from the database. Long story short : Just move the logic of fetching/getting a list of students (based on `teacherId`) from the `Teacher` bean to the `Student` bean itself.

Comment: One clarification of the first comment : "*You could directly inject the (student) list using `@ManagedProperty`, if the target bean (`Student`) is a **request scoped JSF managed bean***". This line is utterly wrong. So here is my apology. In your case, you are navigating to a different URL from an action(Listener) method apparently. Therefore, the source **view scoped** bean (`Teacher`) will be destroyed as soon as the navigation takes place. (The thing was that I thought it with a completely different scenario in my mind where a source view scoped bean was available i.e. was not destroyed)

Comment: You're showing zero code; no way to tell what's wrong without a bunch of guesswork